# Recursion function for finding word in stack automata

Tags: c++, recursion, finite-automata

I have to implement stackautomata in c++ and I have problems with finding if a word is in the language of the automata.Here is my fnction but it is far away from what it should be.
My deltas are stored in a map,string> - (S,a)-> S  all of my rules are of this type.
And for example the

```
  findWord("bac")
```

for stack automata with this deltas (A,a)=A(A,c)=f(S,a)=A(S,b)=A(S,b)=f(S,c)=S
and start S  should return true ,but my function doesn't work properly.

```
bool StackAutomata::findWord(string& word)
{
    if(this->isEmpty())
        return false;
    stack<T> wordInStack;
    for(string::reverse_iterator it = word.rbegin(); it!=word.rend(); it++)
    {
        wordInStack.push(*it);
    }
    string current=this->getStart();
   pair<string&,string&> keypairstart = (current,wordInStack.top());
    findWordRecursion(wordInStack,current);

}
template <typename T>
bool StackAutomata::findWordRecursion(stack<T>& wordInStack,string& current)
{
    if(wordInStack.empty() && current == "f")
        return true;
    pair<string&,string&> keypair = (current,wordInStack.top());
    if(delta.count(keypair)==1)
    {
        list<string> value = delta.find(keypair)->second;
        list<string>::iterator it= value.begin();
        while(it!=value.end() && !false)
        {
            stack<T> CopyStack = wordInStack;
            CopyStack.pop();
            findWordRecursion(CopyStack,*it);
            CopyStack=wordInStack;
        }
    }
    else
    return false
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. What is your code supposed to do? What is the issue you are having?

Comment: We still need a [mre], if you want us to debug your code we need to be able to run it

Comment: `findWordRecursion(wordInStack,current);` - maybe do something with the result of that call rather than ignore it and put a no-return code path in your function. Look closely, you'll see that mistake *twice* and any compiler worth its salt with even trivial warnings enabled should tell you about it.